# Populating a Google From DropDown with Values from a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-sheets-api

I looked through all of the questions, and I can't quite figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is the background:

I created a spreadsheet that has multiple tabs. Each tab corresponds to types of events (e.g parades, festivals, sports). Each of these tabs is used to assign specific job numbers to a specific event. Parade job numbers are in the 2000 range, festivals 3000 range, sports 4000 range.

I then have a different tab which defines an array that collects all of the job numbers and events, and sorts them alphabetically. This tab is called "Active_Job_Numbers".

My goal is to create several forms that call to this spreadsheet for the values on the "Active_Job_Numbers" tab. I sort of have this working, but not completely. Each form has a purpose such as submitting a request to accounting to process a credit card transaction; another form to submit a request to cut a check.

All of these requests have to be tied to an ever changing list of job numbers. When I update the spreadsheet, the dropdown in the spreadsheet will populate based on the  "Active_Job_Numbers" data.

The code that I am using does work, BUT if I update a job number or event name on the spreadsheet, the form still sees the old value. I have triggers set up for onSubmit and onOpen and still, the only way I can get the dropdown in the form to update is if I change one of the "var" labels. Then save it. Then reopen the form. This is a showstopper.

Here is the code I am using:

```
function updateForm(){
  // call your form and connect to the drop-down item
  var creditCardRequestGoogleForm = FormApp.openById("1LqtPLGEhocGdkg75mkdldfplxSxWJmYZCp3u1bMwVQQ");

  var jobNumberDropDown = creditCardRequestGoogleForm.getItemById("1632374512").asListItem();




// identify the sheet where the data resides needed to populate the drop-down
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("17fgel9Jfl4Aske85mfkwsphBQpZgtGhR8Q");
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
  var activeJobNumbers = ss.getSheetByName('Active_Job_Numbers');

  // grab the values in the first column of the sheet - use 2 to skip header row 
  var jobNumValues = activeJobNumbers.getRange(2, 1, activeJobNumbers.getMaxRows() - 1).getValues();

  var jobNums = [];

  // convert the array ignoring empty cells
  for(var i = 0; i < jobNumValues.length; i++)    
    if(jobNumValues[i][0] != "")
      jobNums[i] = jobNumValues[i][0];

  // populate the drop-down with the array data
  jobNumberDropDown.setChoiceValues(jobNums);

}
```

A separate but related problem...there are some forms I have that have two different drop-down elements that call to the same spreadsheet but to different tabs. I am not sure how to group this script so I have to separated out like so:

```
function updateForm(){
  // call your form and connect to the drop-down item
  var ccrForm = FormApp.openById("1r5n6Sr7fhtGCqht_QHy9qWR1v2ESabxdE-bMxjR-M");

  var jobNumberDropDown = ccrForm.getItemById("1678955392").asListItem();




// identify the sheet where the data resides needed to populate the drop-down
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("17eGAlcnBB7ejdfqp3HBQBK9wJAKWYhBQpZgtGhR8Q");
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
  var currentJobNumbers = ss.getSheetByName('Active Job Numbers');

  // grab the values in the first column of the sheet - use 2 to skip header row 
  var jobNumValues = currentJobNumbers.getRange(2, 1, currentJobNumbers.getMaxRows() - 1).getValues();

  var jobNums = [];

  // convert the array ignoring empty cells
  for(var i = 0; i < jobNumValues.length; i++)    
    if(jobNumValues[i][0] != "")
      jobNums[i] = jobNumValues[i][0];

  // populate the drop-down with the array data
  jobNumberDropDown.setChoiceValues(jobNums);

}

function updateForm(){
  // This call your form and connect to the drop-down item
  var form = FormApp.openById("1r5n6Sr7fhtGCqht_QHy9qWR1v2ESabxdE-bMxjR-M");

  var poNumberDropDown = form.getItemById("57865789991").asListItem();




// This is the second dropdown which calls the same spreadsheet but different tab NEED HELP COMBINING THESE TWO MORE ELEGANTLY
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("17eGAlcnBB7ejdfqp3HBQBK9wJAKWYhBQpZgtGhR8Q");
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
  var currentPONumbers = ss.getSheetByName('PO_Number');

  // grab the values in the first column of the sheet - use 2 to skip header row 
  var poNumValues = currentPONumbers.getRange(2, 1, currentPONumbers.getMaxRows() - 1).getValues();

  var poNums = [];

  // convert the array ignoring empty cells
  for(var i = 0; i < poNumValues.length; i++)    
    if(poNumValues[i][0] != "")
      poNums[i] = poNumValues[i][0];

  // populate the drop-down with the array data
  poNumberDropDown.setChoiceValues(poNums);

}
```

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Few questions: 1) The above code is bound to the form or is it bound to the google sheet? 2) Have you tried just running the above code manually, after you edit the google sheet? 3) onSubmit and onOpen have nothing to do with editing the google sheet, they get triggered when someone submits a form or the editor opens the form to edit the form and not when an end user opens the form to submit the form.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The code is bound to the form. My code is not intended to update a sheet. It is merely serving a list to the form dropdown. I took your suggestion and ran the code after making a change on the spreadsheet, and it did update the form. But isn't there a way to ensure the code runs when you open the form?

Comment: Effectively, what I would like to do is if any cell is edited on the spreadsheet, then I want the script attached to the form to run automatically.

Comment: Then use [onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#g_suite_application_triggers) of the spreadsheet to activate the code.

Answer (score 2):

[onOpen trigger for a form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#open_2), as mentioned in documentation:

> This event does not occur when a user opens a form to respond, but
>   rather when an editor opens the form to modify it

Instead, you can use an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) to activate your code when the sheet is edited.

Furthermore, instead of modifying all form each time an edit is made on the spreadsheet. You can check for which sheet is modified in the spreadsheet to modify the corresponding form. To determine the which sheet is modified you can use [event objects.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

Here is example code, you can modify this for your use.

```
function installedEdit(evtObj){
  Logger.log("Edit running")
 var sheetName = evtObj.range.getSheet().getSheetName()
 Logger.log(sheetName)
 var itemId="None"
 switch (sheetName){
   case "Active Job Numbers": 
     itemId = "1678955392"
     updateForm(sheetName,itemId)
     break;
   case "PO_Number":
     itemId = "57865789991"
     updateForm(sheetName,itemId)
     break;
 }
}

function updateForm(sheetName,itemId){
  // call your form and connect to the drop-down item
  var form = FormApp.openById("1r5n6Sr7fhtGCqht_QHy9qWR1v2ESabxdE-bMxjR-M");
  var dropDown = form.getItemById(itemId).asListItem();
// identify the sheet where the data resides needed to populate the drop-down
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("17eGAlcnBB7ejdfqp3HBQBK9wJAKWYhBQpZgtGhR8Q");
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  // grab the values in the first column of the sheet - use 2 to skip header row 
  var choiceValues = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 2).getValues();
  var choices = [];
  // convert the array ignoring empty cells
  for(var i = 0; i < choiceValues.length; i++)    
    if(choiceValues[i][0] != "")
      choices[i] = choiceValues[i][0];
     // populate the drop-down with the array data
     dropDown.setChoiceValues(choices);
  }
```

Note: Make sure `installedEdit()` is set up to run when the spreadsheet is edited and is bound to the spreadsheet.

Comment: Couple of newbie questions about the code: 1) is "edit running" an arbitrary name you assigned to the logger.log? 2) In the first function, is the itemID referring to the specific tab in a google sheet? If so just curious why you are calling it by sheetname and by itemid or am I totaly misunderstanding?  3) Also, in the first function, is sheetname something I need to alter to match my sheetnames? 4) for the second function, the line " var dropDown = form.getItemById(itemId).asListItem();" --I am assuming I need to replace itemid with the data-item-id of the dropdown on the form.

Comment: 1) Link to [Logger.log](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger#logdata). 2)ItemID refers to data-item-id of the dropDown on the form, I got these from the code in your question. 3)sheetnames should match exactly to the sheet name you have in your spreadsheet. Again, I got the names from your code above (please avoid spaces in your sheetname). 4) You will modify the itemId in the case statement in the first function.

Comment: Finally, when in doubt google the statements in google and search for javascript results. Like search: "Switch Javascript" in google to learn about switch syntax. Google script is based on javascript, so if you cannot find something in google script documentation. Please search javascript documentation.

Comment: lol...so learn Javascript from scratch. Got it. At least before, I was further along.

Comment: Based on your question I assumed you knew JavaScript. However, it is not  a too difficult a language to learn.

Comment: I do appreciate the direction. This is literally my first project. I hope you will be open to questions as I run through this.